# How to intercept touches events on a MKMapView or UIWebView objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I try to catch touches on a `MKMapView` object. I subclassed it by creating the following class :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewWithTouches : MKMapView {

}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event;   

@end
```

And the implementation :

```
#import "MapViewWithTouches.h"
@implementation MapViewWithTouches

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {

    NSLog(@"hello");
    //[super touchesBegan:touches   withEvent:event];

}
@end
```

But it looks like when I use this class, I see nothing on the Console :

```
MapViewWithTouches *mapView = [[MapViewWithTouches alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The best way I have found to achieve this is with a Gesture Recognizer.  Other ways turn out to involve a lot of hackish programming that imperfectly duplicates Apple's code, especially in the case of multitouch.

Here's what I do:  Implement a gesture recognizer that cannot be prevented and that cannot prevent other gesture recognizers.  Add it to the map view, and then use the gestureRecognizer's touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc. to your fancy.

### How to detect any tap inside an MKMapView (sans tricks)

```
WildcardGestureRecognizer * tapInterceptor = [[WildcardGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
tapInterceptor.touchesBeganCallback = ^(NSSet * touches, UIEvent * event) {
        self.lockedOnUserLocation = NO;
};
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:tapInterceptor];
```

### WildcardGestureRecognizer.h

```
//
//  WildcardGestureRecognizer.h
//  Copyright 2010 Floatopian LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^TouchesEventBlock)(NSSet * touches, UIEvent * event);

@interface WildcardGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer {
    TouchesEventBlock touchesBeganCallback;
}
@property(copy) TouchesEventBlock touchesBeganCallback;


@end
```

### WildcardGestureRecognizer.m

```
//
//  WildcardGestureRecognizer.m
//  Created by Raymond Daly on 10/31/10.
//  Copyright 2010 Floatopian LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "WildcardGestureRecognizer.h"


@implementation WildcardGestureRecognizer
@synthesize touchesBeganCallback;

-(id) init{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (touchesBeganCallback)
        touchesBeganCallback(touches, event);
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)reset
{
}

- (void)ignoreTouch:(UITouch *)touch forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (BOOL)canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventingGestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)canPreventGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventedGestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

### SWIFT 3

```
let tapInterceptor = WildCardGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil)
tapInterceptor.touchesBeganCallback = {
    _, _ in
    self.lockedOnUserLocation = false
}
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapInterceptor)
```

**WildCardGestureRecognizer.swift**

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class WildCardGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    var touchesBeganCallback: ((Set<UITouch>, UIEvent) -> Void)?

    override init(target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
        self.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        touchesBeganCallback?(touches, event)
    }

    override func canPrevent(_ preventedGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func canBePrevented(by preventingGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: what's "lockedOnUserLocation" for?

Comment: that's an extraneous variable specific to my application.  it keeps track of whether the system should automatically center the map on the current location

Comment: This is perfect solution. I need one clarification: In the method "- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event", what is the purpose of using the code: if (touchesBeganCallback)
        touchesBeganCallback(touches, event);

Comment: This works great for the most part but I have found one problem with it. If the HTML in your web view contains an HTML5 `video` tag with controls, the gesture recognizer will prevent the user from being able to use the controls. I have been looking for a workaround for this but have yet to find one.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Why there isn't a suitable delegate method for tracking user interactions with a map view is beyond me but this works well.

Comment: Great solution, thank you! I needed to dismiss a keyboard if the user taps on my mapview, and this handled it perfectly.

Comment: Works great for a webview aswell.

Comment: I added a delegate and inside every TouchesDid... call I added this type of line:
if ( delegate ) [delegate touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

Also, add a dealloc and call self.touchesBeganCallback = nil for memory handling. Thanks for the code, awesome snips

Comment: @gonzojive Does the gesture recognizer not need a delegate?

Comment: @gonzojive: This example works great for responding to touches immediately but is there a way to have the mapview respond to something more similar to a touch up inside event?

Comment: @markdorison Complete the class by adding a touchedEndedCallback, similar to the one he has.

Comment: This works perfectly but now, I need to know the frame tapped in that callBack or whatever it is. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! It works for me perfectly.We just need to replace this line with your own code: self.lockedOnUserLocation = NO;

Comment: Tried to use this to pass touch events that were happening to a view that is on top of a map view back to the map view.  No luck.  Is it possible to intercept the gesture in the SuperView and then pass it along to all subviews and let all subviews do something?

Comment: i have one doubt. i need an implementation like : - (BOOL)canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventingGestureRecognizer {
    if ([[preventingGestureRecognizer description] rangeOfString:@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer"].location != NSNotFound)
        return NO;
    return [super canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:preventingGestureRecognizer];
}  i am getting an error. "No visible @interface for 'UIGestureRecognizer' declares the selector 'canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:'" any help

Answer (score 29):

After a day of pizzas, screamings, I finally found the solution! Very neat!

Peter, I used your trick above and tweaked it a little bit to finally have a solution which work perfectly with MKMapView and should work also with UIWebView

**MKTouchAppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class UIViewTouch;
@class MKMapView;

@interface MKTouchAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIViewTouch *viewTouch;
    MKMapView *mapView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewTouch *viewTouch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**MKTouchAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "MKTouchAppDelegate.h"
#import "UIViewTouch.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation MKTouchAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewTouch;
@synthesize mapView;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    //We create a view wich will catch Events as they occured and Log them in the Console
    viewTouch = [[UIViewTouch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    //Next we create the MKMapView object, which will be added as a subview of viewTouch
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [viewTouch addSubview:mapView];

    //And we display everything!
    [window addSubview:viewTouch];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];


}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

**UIViewTouch.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class UIView;

@interface UIViewTouch : UIView {
    UIView *viewTouched;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView * viewTouched;

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

**UIViewTouch.m**

```
#import "UIViewTouch.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@implementation UIViewTouch
@synthesize viewTouched;

//The basic idea here is to intercept the view which is sent back as the firstresponder in hitTest.
//We keep it preciously in the property viewTouched and we return our view as the firstresponder.
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Hit Test");
    viewTouched = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    return self;
}

//Then, when an event is fired, we log this one and then send it back to the viewTouched we kept, and voilà!!! :)
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Began");
    [viewTouched touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Moved");
    [viewTouched touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Ended");
    [viewTouched touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Cancelled");
}

@end
```

I hope that will help some of you!

Cheers

Comment: Nice.  Small suggestion: You should avoid naming your own classes with a UI prefix.  Apple reserves/discourages using NS or UI as a class prefix, because these might end up clashing with an Apple class (even if it's a private class).

Comment: Hey Daniel,

You are perfectly right, I thought that too!

To complete my answer above, let me add a little warning : My Example assume there's only one object viewTouched, which are consuming all the events. But that's not true. You could have some Annotations on top of your Map and then my code doesn't work anymore. To work 100%, you need to remember for each hitTest the view associated to that specific event (and eventually release it when touchesEnded or touchesCancelled is triggered so you don't need to keep track of finished events...).

Comment: Very useful code, thanks Martin!  I was wondering if you tried pinch-zooming the map after implementing this?  For me when I got it working using basically the same code you have above everything seemed to work except pinch zooming the map.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hey Adam,

I also have this limitation and I don't really understand why! That really is annoying. If you find a solution, let me know! Thx

Comment: Ok, I voted this one up because it initially appeared to solve my problem.

HOWEVER...!

I can't seem to get multi-touch to work.  That is, even though I directly pass touchesBegan and touchesMoved to viewTouched (I do my intercepting on touchesEnded), I cannot zoom the map with pinch gestures.

(Continued...)

Comment: (Continued from above.)  In fact, this code:

  In fact, this code:

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Map touch-began count: %d", [touches count]);
    [viewTouched touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Moved: %d", [touches count]);
    [viewTouched touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

Yields this log output on attempted pinch/zoom:

  Map touch-began count: 1
  Touch Moved: 1
  Touch Moved: 1

[etc., snip]

Help?!

Comment: (Bah!  That went poorly.  Hopefully someone with edit privileges can fix that.)

Comment: Wow! Nicely done. Next question: Can I detect when a PIN is tapped (and the annotation/callout pops into view)? I don't see a way to do that yet. :(

Comment: Should I be creating a delegate that is set in UIViewTouch to be called in one of the touches method?

For example, I am embedding my version of UIViewTouch (which i call MiniMapViewTouch) in a custom UITableViewCell. When the UIViewTouch is clicked, I want it to perform a method in the custom cell. Therefore, I should create a delegate, set it, and then show the UIViewTouch correct?

Comment: I ended up creating a delegate chain and it worked well.

This answer was spot on. Thank you!

Comment: You should release the touchView and mapView in your app delegate's dealloc method.

Comment: Great ! will this work for uiwebview ? i mean for pinching events as well ?

Answer (score 24):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];   
tgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
tgr.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
[tgr release];


- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        return;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

    //.............
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't the top answer. Seems to work perfectly, and is much simpler.

Answer (score 12):

### For a MKMapView the real working solution is with gesture recognization !

Me I wanted to stop updating the center of the map on my location when I drag the map or pinch to zoom.

So, create and add your gesture recognizer to the mapView :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    ...

    // Add gesture recognizer for map hoding
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressAndPinchGesture:)] autorelease];
    longPressGesture.delegate = self;
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0;  // In order to detect the map touching directly (Default was 0.5)
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

    // Add gesture recognizer for map pinching
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressAndPinchGesture:)] autorelease];
    pinchGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

    // Add gesture recognizer for map dragging
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)] autorelease];
    panGesture.delegate = self;
    panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;  // In order to discard dragging when pinching
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}
```

Look the [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see all available gesture recognizer.

Because we've defined the delegate to self, we have to implement the protocole UIGestureRecognizerDelegate :

```
typedef enum {
    MapModeStateFree,                    // Map is free
    MapModeStateGeolocalised,            // Map centred on our location
    MapModeStateGeolocalisedWithHeading  // Map centred on our location and oriented with the compass
} MapModeState;

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
    MapModeState mapMode;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
...
```

And override the methode gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: in order to allow recognize multiple gestures simultaneously, if I understood right :

```
// Allow to recognize multiple gestures simultaneously (Implementation of the protocole UIGestureRecognizerDelegate)
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Now write the methodes which will be called by our gesture recognizers :

```
// On map holding or pinching pause localise and heading
- (void)handleLongPressAndPinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    // Stop to localise and/or heading
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan && mapMode != MapModeStateFree) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        if (mapMode == MapModeStateGeolocalisedWithHeading) [locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
    }
    // Restart to localise and/or heading
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && mapMode != MapModeStateFree) {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        if (mapMode == MapModeStateGeolocalisedWithHeading) [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    }
}

// On dragging gesture put map in free mode
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan && mapMode != MapModeStateFree) [self setMapInFreeModePushedBy:sender];
}
```

Comment: This solution is perfect! Some quickies here: If you want to intercep when user ends making any action using this should be enought - (void)handleLongPressAndPinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"handleLongPressAndPinchGesture Ended");
    }
}

Comment: Also do not forget to add the delegate <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

Answer (score 8):

Just in case somebody is trying to do the same like me: I wanted to create an annotation at the point where the user taps. For that I used the `UITapGestureRecognizer` solution:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnMap:)];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];

- (void)didTapOnMap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
    .......
}
```

However, `didTapOnMap:` was also called when I tapped on the annotation and a new one would be created. The solution is to implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[MKAnnotationView class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution ! But it's not working if you use a custom view as `MKAnnotation`. In this case, you may have another annotation's subview triggering the gesture recognizer.
I had to recursively check the superview of the touch.view to find a potential MKAnnotationView

Answer (score 3):

You probably will need to overlay a transparent view to catch the touches just like is done so often with UIWebView-based controls.  The Map View already does a bunch of special things with a touch in order to allow the map to be moved, centered, zoomed, etc... that the messages are not getting bubbled up to your app.

Two other (UNTESTED) options I can think of:

1)  Resign the first responder via IB and set it to "File's Owner" to allow file's Owner to respond to the touches.  I an dubious that this will work because MKMapView extends NSObject, not UIView ans a result the touch events still may not get propagated up to you.

2)  If you want to trap when the Map state changes (such as on a zoom) just implement the MKMapViewDelegate protocol to listen for particular events.  My hunch is this is your best shot at trapping some interaction easily (short of implementing the transparent View over the Map).  Do not forget to set the View Controller housing the MKMapView as the map's delegate (`map.delegate = self`).

Good Luck.

Comment: MKMapView definitely subclasses UIView.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't experimented, but there's a good chance MapKit is based around a class cluster, and therefore subclassing it is difficult and ineffective.

I'd suggest making the MapKit view a subview of a custom view, which should allow you to intercept touch events before they reach it.

Comment: Hello Graham!

Thank you for your help! If I make a super custom view like you suggest, how could I then forward events to the MKMapView? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

So after half a day of messing around with this I found the following:

1. As everyone else found, pinching doesn't work. I tried both subclassing MKMapView and the method described above (intercepting it). And the result is the same.
2. In the Stanford iPhone videos, a guy from Apple says that many of the UIKit things will
   cause alot of errors if you "transfer" the touch requests (aka the two methods described above), and you probably won't get it to work.
3. **THE SOLUTION**: is described here: [Intercepting/Hijacking iPhone Touch Events for MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121889/intercepting-hijacking-iphone-touch-events-for-mkmapview/1298330). Basically you "catch" the event before any responder gets it, and interpret it there.

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 3.0**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class CoordinatesPickerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(clickOnMap))
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func clickOnMap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.ended { return }
        let touchLocation = sender.location(in: mapView)
        let locationCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        print("Tapped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the MKMapView a subview of a custom view and implement

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in the custom view to return self instead of the subview.

Comment: Hello Peter, Thanks for your answer!

But I think that by doing that, the MKMapView might not be able to get any touche events, isn't it?

I'm looking for a way to just catch event and then forward it to the  MKMapView.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pizza and screamings - you saved me lots of time.

multipletouchenabled will work sporadically.

```
viewTouch.multipleTouchEnabled = TRUE;
```

In the end, I switched out the views when I needed to capture the touch (different point in time than needing pinchzooms):

```
    [mapView removeFromSuperview];
    [viewTouch addSubview:mapView];
    [self.view insertSubview:viewTouch atIndex:0];
```

Comment: but does not work with live zooming. It also seems to always zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you can track the number and location of touches, and get the location of each in a view:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Moved %d", [[event allTouches] count]);

 NSEnumerator *enumerator = [touches objectEnumerator];
 id value;

 while ((value = [enumerator nextObject])) {
  NSLog(@"touch description %f", [value locationInView:mapView].x);
 }
    [viewTouched touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Has anyone else tried using these values to update the map's zoom level? It would be a matter of recording the start positions, and then the finish locations, calculating the relative difference and updating the map.

I'm playing with the basic code provided by Martin, and this looks like it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I put together, that does allow pinch zooms in the simulator (haven't tried on a real iPhone), but I think would be fine:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Began %d", [touches count]);
 reportTrackingPoints = NO;
 startTrackingPoints = YES;
    [viewTouched touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 if ([[event allTouches] count] == 2) {
  reportTrackingPoints = YES;
  if (startTrackingPoints == YES) {
   BOOL setA = NO;
   NSEnumerator *enumerator = [[event allTouches] objectEnumerator];
   id value;
   while ((value = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    if (! setA) {
     startPointA = [value locationInView:mapView];
     setA = YES;
    } else {
     startPointB = [value locationInView:mapView];
    }
   }
   startTrackingPoints = NO;
  } else {
   BOOL setA = NO;
   NSEnumerator *enumerator = [[event allTouches] objectEnumerator];
   id value;
   while ((value = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    if (! setA) {
     endPointA = [value locationInView:mapView];
     setA = YES;
    } else {
     endPointB = [value locationInView:mapView];
    }
   }
  }
 }
 //NSLog(@"Touch Moved %d", [[event allTouches] count]);
    [viewTouched touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) updateMapFromTrackingPoints {
 float startLenA = (startPointA.x - startPointB.x);
 float startLenB = (startPointA.y - startPointB.y);
 float len1 = sqrt((startLenA * startLenA) + (startLenB * startLenB));
 float endLenA = (endPointA.x - endPointB.x);
 float endLenB = (endPointA.y - endPointB.y);
 float len2 = sqrt((endLenA * endLenA) + (endLenB * endLenB));
 MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
 region.span.latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta * len1/len2;
 region.span.longitudeDelta = region.span.longitudeDelta * len1/len2;
 [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 if (reportTrackingPoints) {
  [self updateMapFromTrackingPoints];
  reportTrackingPoints = NO;
 }


    [viewTouched touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The main idea is that if the user is using two fingers, you track the values. I record the starting and ending points in startPoints A and B. Then I record the current tracking points, and when I'm done, on touchesEnded, I can call a routine to calculate the relative lengths of the line between the points I start with, and the line between the point I end with using simple hypotenuse calc. The ratio between them is the zoom amount: I multiply the region span by that amount.

Hope it's useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I took the idea of an "overlay" transparent view, from MystikSpiral's answer, and it worked perfectly for what I was trying to achieve; quick, and clean solution.

In short, I had a custom UITableViewCell (designed in IB) with a MKMapView on the left-hand-side and some UILabels on the right.  I wanted to make the custom cell so you could touch it anywhere and this would push a new view controller.  However touching the map didn't pass touches 'up' to the UITableViewCell until I simply added a UIView of the same size as the map view right on top of it (in IB) and made it's background the 'clear color' in code (don't think you can set clearColor in IB??):

```
dummyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Thought it might help someone else; certainly if you want to achieve the same behaviour for a table view cell.

Comment: "However touching the map didn't pass touches 'up' to the UITableViewCell until I simply added a UIView of the same size as the map view right on top of it" 
This is not true. The map is processing touches because it has it's own user interactions such as scrolling etc. 
If you want to detect the though on the cell instead of interacting with the map, simply set map.isUserInteractionEnabled = false 
You can then just use didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the table view delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why other answers are so complicated. The solution is really just one line:

```
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapTapped)))

@objc func mapTapped() {}
```