# Display a view at the bottom of a map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm looking for a solution to display a view when I select a mkannotation in my map. In the image:

[image]

If you selected a mkannotation, it is displayed the view that in the bottom. I have a way but I don't know if it's the best. It's just display the view under the map, like subview of the general view, but the problem I see it's that it was above the map, hiding a part of this, and I don't know how to detect that the user click on the map to hide the view of the profile.

Thanks in advance

Edit 1.
With this code, I get errors, and if I fix it add .view to the errors, these disappear, but then when I select a mkannotation it doesn't appear nothing.

[image]

Comment: check these links [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275731/iphone-detecting-tap-in-mkmapview)[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first time create i YourViewController.xib and in your mapviewcontroller use this code :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    if(![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        YourViewController *calloutView = (YourViewController *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        CGRect calloutViewFrame = calloutView.frame;
        calloutViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(-calloutViewFrame.size.width/2 + 15, -calloutViewFrame.size.height);
        calloutView.frame = calloutViewFrame;

        [calloutView.calloutLabel setText:[(locationAnnotation*)[view annotation] title]];
        [calloutView.CallDattabel setText:[(locationAnnotation*)[view annotation] subtitle]];
        [calloutView.status setText:[(locationAnnotation*)[view annotation] status]];
        [calloutView.ImageSate setImage:[(locationAnnotation*)[view annotation] image ]];
        [view addSubview:calloutView];
    }

}
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews ){
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

i hope this code is useful for you

Comment: what do I need before? create a uiviewcontroller with its .xib? Because I cant get working that code

Comment: create new file cmd+n and chose Objective-c class ViewController and subclass of UIViewController and  check also create XIB file

Comment: in your Pruebalpreviewcontroller use in fichier.h : @interface Pruebalpreviewcontroller : UIView

Comment: @Juanjo and in fichier.m use : 
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: @Juanjo and in your Pruebalpreviewcontroller.xib chos in simulated Matrics size freeform  and status bar none

Comment: I did it and nothing, I get a black screen when I click a MKAnnotation

Comment: @Juanjo so custom your fichier.XIB with UILabel and send your data in UIlabel ok
for exemple [calloutView.calloutLabel setText:@"your name here"];

Comment: I did it, I have my custom .xib with white blackgroundColor and a label, but nothing. Don't you have a sample project or extended tutorial?

Comment: look for this exemple http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/advanced-mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-custom-callout/