# Detect 2 fingers on screen on mapView MapKit

Tags: iphone, events, mapkit, zooming

I try to detect the event on a mapview. I just need to detect zoom (double tap or 2 fingers on screen). I try to add a UIview layer that detect event, but if I add a layer, I lose the control on the map ([How to intercept touches events on a MKMapView or UIWebView objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects/1403063#1403063))

Thanks for help!

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Show us some code.  You should be able to pass any events you are not interested in back to the parent view.  For example, after you detect a two finger tap, and do whatever you want, pass that same event back to mapview and have it zoom itself.

Here is what you call once you are done with your event detection:

```
[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

Answer (score 0):

According this: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121889/intercepting-hijacking-iphone-touch-events-for-mkmapview/1383374#1383374)

The Mkmapview has to be the default receiver of the events.

So I change the class of my main window to MyMainWindow:

**MyMainWindow.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class TouchListener;

@interface MyMainWindow : UIWindow {    

TouchListener *Touch;

}

@end
```

**MyMainWindow.m**

```
 #import "MyMainWindow.h"

 @implementation MyMainWindow

 - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent*)event {  
 [super sendEvent:event];  
 [Touch sendEvent:event];
 }
 @end
```

**TouchListener.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface TouchListener : UIView {

}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

**TouchListeners.m**

```
#import "TouchListener.h"

@implementation TouchListener

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 return self;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 NSLog(@"Moved");
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Began");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Ended");
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch Cancel");
}

@end
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks for help