# How to forward touches to MKMapView

Tags: iphone, touch, mkmapview, gesture-recognition

how do I forward touches from the parent view that, in my case, is a MKMapView?

The idea, basically, is to splash a view with a spinner that is semi-transparent but I, also, want the user to move the map beyond this view. I just want to pretend the view isn't there and this view just forwards the touches on the parent view (since this spinner view is a subview of MKMapView).

I found a bad way to do that (I sincerely haven't tried it and I don't think I will) that is using some undocumented APIs:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIScrollView * view = [[[[mapView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [view touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I have also found the `WildcardGestureRecognizer` approach as discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121889/intercepting-hijacking-iphone-touch-events-for-mkmapview/1298330) but I think it is so much powerful compared to the trivial goal I am trying to achieve.

Any ideas on how to do this easily?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is enough to set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` on the overlay view. IIRC, the underlying view will then receive the touches.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm brand new here. Done!