# Detect zoom in and zoom out in map with touch event in iphone sdk

Tags: ios4

How to detect zoom in and zoom out of UIMapView (in UIMapKit) with touch events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166444/mkmapview-zoom-and-region)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121889/intercepting-hijacking-iphone-touch-events-for-mkmapview