# IBAction to another class not working?

Tags: iphone, class, ibaction

I've got two classes and I have declared some methods in one class that I want to use in the other one. The first view is a scrollview that loads a detailview. Here's is one of the methods in the detailview:

```
-(IBAction)savePic {  
    UIImage *imageView = coverImageView.image;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView, nil, nil, nil);  
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                                                      message:@"Picture saved to Camera Roll!" 
                                                     delegate:self 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideAlert:) userInfo:myAlert repeats:NO] retain];

    [myAlert show];

    [myAlert release];
}
```

In the scrollview I have imported the detailview header and created a method like this:

```
-(IBAction)save{  
    DetailViewController *saving = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [saving savePic];
    [saving release];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I got it to work now but it doesn't save the picture...if I try the method in the detailview it works just fine.

Comment: I think it's very similar to another Q..see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/7979134/251513

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly that you can call the IBACTION from one class to another, but why you want to do in that way why can't you create a method and call that method in another class.

Calling a method like VOID,ID process will be easy, since IBACTION is a property of some action (e.g. button). You need to send some action message till then the IBACTION won't be called.

Comment: IBAction is defined as void. You can call an IBAction in the same way you call a void method.