# May I restrict zoom levels of MKMapView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there way to limit MKMapView maximum zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636868/is-there-way-to-limit-mkmapview-maximum-zoom-level)

May I restrict zoom levels of MKMapView, i.e., set max and min zoom levels of `MKMapView`?