# Detecting panning + decelerate of MKMapView

Tags: uiscrollview, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I'm trying to capture panning and the 'end of scrolling' on an MKMapView. Panning is easy to do with a gesture recognizer. However, MKMapView doesn't seem to implement a UIScrollViewDelegate in iOS 6. That makes the solution in [Is there way to limit MKMapView maximum zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636868/is-there-way-to-limit-mkmapview-maximum-zoom-level) not work.

Thoughts? Ideally I would have just leveraged the UIScrollViewDelegate as such:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:)]) {
        [super scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView];
    }
    [self.myDelegate mapDidFinishPanning:self];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:    (BOOL)decelerate {
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndDragging:)]) {
        [super scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView];
    }

if(!decelerate) {
    [self.myDelegate mapDidFinishPanning:self];
}
```

}

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewWillBeginDragging:)]) {
        [super scrollViewWillBeginDragging:scrollView];
    }
    [self.myDelegate mapDidBeginPanning:self];
}
```

inside a class extending MKMapView

```
@interface MyMapView : MKMapView <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

but that won't work in iOS 6. I can't see anything sufficient in MKMapViewDelegate.

Comment: Update: a couple of MKMapViewDelegate's methods seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering myself. I implemented all of MKMapViewDelegate's methods and it seems that

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

is called on pan, and

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

is called as soon as deceleration stops (and not before).

Comment: To add to this, regionDidChange is also called if they keep panning (even if it doesn't decelerate completely), so I had to use some time based logic.

Comment: can you give a time based logic?