# Detecting when MKMapView has stopped moving

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

Whenever the user moves my MKMapView, I load more pins on to the map. Right now, I am using this code to detect when they drag it:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didDragMap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeft, bottomRight;
        topLeft = [self.mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
        CGPoint pointBottomRight = CGPointMake(self.mapView.frame.size.width, self.mapView.frame.size.height);
        bottomRight = [self.mapView convertPoint:pointBottomRight toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

        [self loadMorePlaces:topLeft bottomRight:bottomRight];
    }
}
```

However, this only detects when a user stopped dragging. A user can "fling" the map and the map can still be moving AFTER they finish "dragging". Is there a way I can find when the map stops moving? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108801/detecting-panning-decelerate-of-mkmapview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this delegate:

[mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:)