# MKMapView setting zoom limit without bouncing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

There is a lot of questions and answers on stackoverflow about max zoom for MKMapView, for exmaple:

[Is there way to limit MKMapView maximum zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636868/is-there-way-to-limit-mkmapview-maximum-zoom-level)

Unfortunately non of the answers actually worked for me (or I just did not implement correctly). I was not able to simulate the behavior that native map has, that would be - restricting zoom level without 'bouncing' or resuming back.

This is my code that used:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    if( mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta<0.001 || mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta<0.001){
        MKCoordinateRegion region =mapView.region;
        region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001);
        mapView.region = region;
        [mapView setRegion:mapView.region animated:NO];
    }
}
```

When a user pinch and zoom map and the map reaches the max zoom (set by me), the map should not zoom in and then bounce back. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

With my knowledge, I don't think it's actually possible to set max zoom or min zoom without making it yourself. But I know that if you use the Google Map SDK, you can actually set a max and a min zoom for the map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view