# iOS: Maximum Zoom while Setting a Region in MapKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to get my mapView to zoom in fairly close by using the setRegion function.

My problem is that, while testing, it seems that setRegion doesn't want to zoom in more than to a span of about 0.01 or so, even though I can manually pinch to zoom in closer than that.

What's stopping this? Will setRegion not allow me to zoom in closer?

Comment: It seems 0.01 span is the max. Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636868/is-there-way-to-limit-mkmapview-maximum-zoom-level

Comment: @SaurabhShukla Thanks for the link. I don't see anything there about 0.01 being the max though? Is there a way to override that?