# Is there a minimum span in an MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = 
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 10, 10);

[self.mapView setRegion:region];
```

This is my code but it doesn't work correctly.

I have a map with my current location and some annotations.
Now I want to show only the annotations which are in a radius of 10 meters.

Is there a minimum radius? If I take 1000m it works correctly!

Comment: After you set the region can you manually zoom in on the map?

Comment: Note that if you want annotations within a 10m radius, you should set the region to be at least 20m wide and high, not 10m.

Comment: no matter if it's 10m or 20m, there is no change. With setregion the minimum is 280m, then there is no change, but manually I can zoom to about 10m??!!

Comment: No but this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/1636868/656600