# Set Minimum Zoom Level For MKMapView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, mkmapview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to set **minimum** and **maximum** **Pinch-In** and **Pinch-Out** Zoomming Level For MKMapview. so user not Pinch after specific Level Of MKMapview Zooming.Currently I am using **MKMapView+ZoomLevel** Category Class to restrict Zoom-In and Out effect of MapView.

Code:-

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

 if([self.mapView zoomLevel]<17) {

  CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = {latitude, longitude};
        [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:centerCoord zoomLevel:17 animated:NO];
}
}
```

Comment: check T Markle & Azdev Answer. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636868/is-there-way-to-limit-mkmapview-maximum-zoom-level)

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani yes i have used that code but its for maximum zoom level i want to set mimim zoom level MKMapview not able to pinch using minimum zoom level.