# How can I automatically zoom out on MKMapView to the point where the tiles load in iOS?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

For my application I have it so my map view zooms in automatically to show about 20km from the users current location on the map (with the user's current location being right in the centre). The problem is that when I test my application on the iPad, for some reason the tiles do not load when it is zoomed in this much. It is only when I zoom out that the tiles will load. I want my application to accomplish the following...

```
if(tiles do not show when map is zoomed out to default of 20km from user's current location)
    zoom out the map until tiles do show
```

I want this to be taken care of automatically because I don't think it looks good if a user sees unloaded tiles. They may not know that zooming out will show the tiles. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Try calculate the distance between the tile and user's current location, add set the zoom level

Comment: Answers in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1636868/2177402) might give you some idea