# MKMapView set maximum zoom

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming

I am rendering a building's indoor map into `MKMapView` using overlays. The building is quite small in top view. I set the desired span using

```
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

so that building can be seen in detail.
I want to let the user zoom out and then zoom in back using pinch,
but when the user scales the map with a pinch gesture, it zooms out and cannot be zoomed in back. So I only can zoom in back programmatically calling `mapView setRegion:animated:` again.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636868/is-there-way-to-limit-mkmapview-maximum-zoom-level

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik they want to not allow to zoom too much. I want to allow to zoom much.