# MKMapView avoid blank tiles [iOS 8+]

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

In `MKMapView` in some zoom lvl  all map tiles are blank. 
I try [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6399683/911564) with max zoom.
For now I use it like this:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        userSpan = mapView.region.span
        if mapView.zoomLevel() > maxZoomLvl
        {
            mapView.setCenterCoordinate(mapView.centerCoordinate, zoomLevel: maxZoomLvl, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

But when user zoom to max lvl it zoom back with animation. But I need some solution like in native apple map application: just block in max zoom without ability to  zoom deep and without zoom back.
Expected result:

1. Avoid bland tiles in max zoom and zoom back bounce (like it work now with current solution)
2. Map should stop zooming if there no tiles (Like native apple map app)  OR map should scale last visible tiles(like google maps app)

Comment: what is the issue you are facing here, as I understand that you are seeing blank tiles when you try to zoom in, also I see that you want to block the max zoom level. Can you please elaborate more.

Comment: @SantoshGurram look in "Expected result"

Comment: Could you provide some screenshot with blank tiles?

Comment: @k8mil Yes, https://gyazo.com/7e0238de24e26cdb661689ad0622e1c0
iPhone 5, iOS 9

Comment: what is the value of maxZoomLvl ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya ~18 but I thinks it doesn't matter.

Comment: try it with 17 @UnRewa and check output

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `mapView.camera` which is an `MKMapCamera` object.

From the docs -

> var altitude: CLLocationDistance
>
> The altitude above the ground, measured in meters.

Just need to find a good value for altitude. From this answer, [Is there way to limit MKMapView maximum zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636868/is-there-way-to-limit-mkmapview-maximum-zoom-level/21470812#21470812)

It seems like following might help you-

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
// enforce maximum zoom level
if (_mapView.camera.altitude < 120.00 && !_modifyingMap) {
    _modifyingMap = YES; // prevents strange infinite loop case

    _mapView.camera.altitude = 120.00;

    _modifyingMap = NO;
}
}
```

Comment: When you release fingers zoom jump back... I think I shouldn't use  regionDidChangeAnimated because it will be zoom back in any solution