# touchesBegan not responding

Tags: objective-c

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        NSLog(@" touches ");
    }

The above method is not calling in my apps. My application description is as under.

I have a `MainViewController` which loads a `ContentViewController` in it. `ContentViewController` has a webview which loads a pdf file.

How to listen the tap of `MainViewController's` View.

Regards.

Comment: This answer is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7808238/790198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be not 100% accurate here, but if you place `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` in your view controller (or its main view) then you will get only those touches that have not been handled by some subviews in the view hierarchy. To intercept all touches you should use UIView subclass for your controller view and override `hitTest:withEvent:` method in it:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchedView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    NSSet* touches = [event allTouches];
    // handle touches if you need
    return touchedView;
}
```

For more information see [Event delivery](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW4) section in "Event handling guide" for iOS

Comment: Updated answer with the link to event handling explanation in Apple docs - it seems it confirms my answer

Comment: I did this. Its working. But now UIWebView has stopped working.

Comment: What does not work exactly? Do you return correct view from hitTest method?

Comment: Please see the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects