# How can I detect scroll events in Safari on iPad with VoiceOver engaged?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, voiceover

I'm working on VoiceOver support for our literacy web site http://tarheelreader.org. When VoiceOver is off, I can use the touch events to allow swiping to turn pages in the book. When VoiceOver is on, and I use a 3-finger swipe I get the clunk sound but no events that I have been able to detect.

I've looked at scroll, touchmove, etc but no joy. Is there some trick that will allow me to notice a three-finger swipe left or quick-nav keyboard option right arrow?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221308/firing-touchesbegan-on-a-mkmapview-with-voiceover-enabled/4963657#4963657 is not exactly what I wanted but related. Double-tap hold until the sound, then swipe works.

Comment: Hi GaryBishop, I'm having a similar issue on project. I think this could be related to the fact that VO simulates touch events and if those touches are outside of the bounds of the window, touch events don't fire. Let me know if you find a solution to this! Good luck