# MapView can't respond to touchesBegin event

Tags: iphone, touch, mkmapview

I have Mapview when i click on mapview it doesn't respond to touchesBegin method.i must missing something but i don't get it.
Please help to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects) post will solve your problem.