# Detect touches on webview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, touch

I want to check either the user touches on webview or not, when user touch on webview then I do something like call function how it is possible?

I have used *"touchbegin"* function but touch begin did not detect touch on webview?

Comment: Use guestures and improve your accept-rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this question it might help you

[How to intercept touches events on a MKMapView or UIWebView objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects)