# MKMapView stops on scrolling, after scrolling to the bottom and trigger Control Center

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer, control-center

I'm facing a weird problem, the map view was working fine, but now there seems a problem.

When i scroll down to the bottom of the screen and then scroll up, the control center is triggered. And after that the map would stop on processing my touches.

I'm using a GestureRecognizer attached on the mapview because i need to handle the touch inside certain regions. When i don't add this recognizer, the problem does not occur.

But if i'm using the recognizer, and i'm listening to what's being triggered, i can see that even after the problem occurs, the recognizer still receives all kinds of touches!!!

So it seems there's a problem in the ios framework, once the control center is triggered, and there's a gesture recognizer on the mkmapview, the mkmapview is losing functionality.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

Update:

Addtionally the problem occur if you perform the aforementioned behavior only on the left half of the screen. If you were scrolling down to the control center but in the right half, and scrol up. the bug does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the WildGestureRecognizer from this:
[How to intercept touches events on a MKMapView or UIWebView objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects)

so i changed it. and i used a simple UITapGestureRecognizer, and i made the handling to the detected tap, and checked its region with no problem.