# forward touch events to UIWebView from overlaying UIView / how to make touch events to uiwebview from code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

Imagine a `UIWebView` that is partly overlayed by a `UIView` which itself has to receive touches.

All I want to do is forward the touch events from the overlaying `UIView` to the `UIWebView`. I tried subclassing the `UIView` and forward the touches to `UIWebView` like

```
[webview touchesbegan:touches withEvent: event]
```

but it isn't working.

Well, it works as far as I can see by subclassing the `UIWebView` that `touchesbegan` gets called. But this never happens when I touch the `UIWebview` directly so this is obviously not the right way to do this. Sooo, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: thanks for formating my text! It looks much better now. I will try it myself the next time...

Comment: I think you want to use gestureRecognizer on the webView, too. this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects?rq=1) has a few variations.

Comment: I will look into it, but I don't want to capture whole screen, only the part where the overlaying UIViews are ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the javascript

```
NSString *javaScript = @"document.getElementById('id_username').value = 'tfusername'";
```

to set value on any of the data
You can send click on any object by fetching its Id 
and then by evaluating it to send event.

```
NSString *myval =  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.querySelector('input[type=\"submit\"][value=\"Log in\"]').click();"];
```

May be this is what you are asking for. Thanks

Comment: sorry. i want to forward a native touch event to uiwebview .. nothing with javascript